# Will $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] detect a site as a referer if it is using a redirect?

Tags: php

In PHP I see that

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

gives me the refering url if the refering page had a link that was clicked through to my current page. But what if page A has a htaccess redirect that sends the user to page B. If I have the above snippet on Page B will I get Page A as the referer?

Or does it only work if a user clicks on a link that takes them to page B?

Comment: The client sends that header, there's never a guarantee that you do or don't receive it.

Comment: Some browsers actually allow you to turn this off, so you never see a referrer. You can never rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To begin with: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php**

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

---

**To answer your question:**

Page A will be sent if it is silent rewrite (temporary redirect).

Page B will be sent  if it is a redirect that sends a 301 (permanent redirect).

Answer (score 0):

If by redirecting you mean rewriting, then as far as the client is concerned, the URL requested is what was returned, and that will be the referrer.